# Total number of videos uploaded by a channel?

Tags: youtube, upload

In YouTube, is it possible to know the total number of videos uploaded by a channel without actually counting it?

I am only able to see the total number of "Video views" and not the number of videos uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open any video it will display the owner's name and the total amount of videos they have to the right, like below:
[image]

If this doesn't work for you, use the [answer by Geniusknight](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66643/60818).

Comment: Okay, I was seeing the channels page and not any video uploaded by them.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, please update.

Answer (score 8):

Working as of **June 2020**:

1. Simply search the channel name

[image]

2. Go to the channel's Videos page (at `https://www.youtube.com/user/username/videos`) by clicking on the channel and then clicking on "Videos" tab. Next to "Uploads" there is a link titled "Play All" which takes you to a playlist of all uploads. The playlist will list how many total videos have been uploaded and are publicly viewable.

[image]

[image]

3. Use `youtube-dl` to see how many videos are in the "Uploaded" playlist.

```
$ youtube-dl --flat-playlist https://www.youtube.com/user/adric22 
[youtube:user] adric22: Downloading channel page
[youtube:playlist] UU8uT9cgJorJPWu7ITLGo9Ww: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: Uploads from The 8-Bit Guy
[youtube:playlist] UU8uT9cgJorJPWu7ITLGo9Ww: Downloading page #1
[youtube:playlist] playlist Uploads from The 8-Bit Guy: Downloading 194 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 194
[download] Downloading video 2 of 194
[download] Downloading video 3 of 194
[download] Downloading video 4 of 194
[download] Downloading video 5 of 194
```

and so on.

Comment: Searching seems to be the only option working right now without using third party tools.

Answer (score 6):

For the updated YouTube interface, you just need to **hover over the Channel Owner's name just below the video** and a popup overlay shows up showing all subscribers and amount of videos uploaded.

Some YouTube users keep their videos private, which can only be accessed when you subscribe to them. In such a case, getting the number of videos uploaded is a bit difficult if you haven't subscribed to them as you only see the videos uploaded under their name.

Comment: Nowadays, that works!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This seems to work _only_ when you are using Chrome. Other browsers just show ellipses where the numbers should be.

Comment: This seems to have been removed in the current version of the website :/

Answer (score 3):

As of **2017** or so, none of the public methods (i.e., methods that don't require an API token) on this page are working. Here's a method that *does* work as of lately (mid-2018):

Change the **UC** prefix of the channel ID to **UU** and use it to access its playlist page. Note that you will change the URL pattern from `…/channel/UC…` to `…/playlist?list=UU…` when you use the **UU** form of the **channelId**. For example:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA
                                ^^--- 'UC'

                                      vv--- 'UU' 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUK8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA
```

On the playlist page, you will see the number of videos currently available in the channel:

[image]

Comment: Not very clearly explained but it actually works (07/2019). Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

***[EDIT] As commenter @Husky mentions, GData is no longer available. Original answer left below for archival purposes.***

You can also access it via the API, just point your browser to the following URL (after replacing TheChannel by your channel name), and read the value for totalItems:

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/TheChannel/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=0
```

Source: [Illiou on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/29pbv2/is_it_still_possible_to_see_how_many_videos_a/cjxsxtj).

Comment: Unfortunately this option no longer works because GData has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a tool like this to get that kind of stats for a channel/user/playlist.
http://youtube-playlist-analyzer.appspot.com/

Comment: This link is dead, sadly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YouTube data API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list). This tool is aimed for developers but it is easy enough to use. Here is a screenshot where I counted the videos from the channel "Cours de japonais !". I've put a black border around the relevant information which can be found at the bottom of the page after the query has been ran.

There are three important information to provide :

1. part : "id" is enough, we don't really care the value, we just need one.
2. channelId : It can be found in the url of the channel page. Here is an example url where the channelId is "UChFfLNTK64xQj7NscGmLLLg" : "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChFfLNTK64xQj7NscGmLLLg".
3. type : Put "video" or it will also query other stuff.

[image: query result screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to https://ytexplore.com and enter the Channel ID or URL to **see the total number of the videos that the channel has along with the total duration of all those videos**. It will also show the playlist counts, custom URL, channel creation date and much more useful information

This web app can also show the **total duration of a playlist** and also several other essential video metrics. If you don’t understand how to do it. [Watch the YouTube video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28Xw1iO0kyY)

[image]